# Select from active cell to specific cell above

Tags: excel, vba

Actually I’m new in macro. I was handling a report for which I was preparing macro, but not able to code particular function. Can someone please help me with coding.
- Excel has a data where column A contains “date”, column B has numeric value with heading “Sample1” & so on. I’m looking for a code which find current date in column A & make a selection with color from range activecell (current date) till above A2 (just below the header) & till column D (right side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Column A date is sorted in Ascending order then you can use the following code or else modify the code according to your requirement.(In my case when button click following code run)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Cells(1, 1) = Now
    Dim Row As Long, Col As Long
    Row = 2
    Do While Cells(Row, 1).Value <> ""
        If Cells(Row, 1).Value <= Date Then
            For Col = 1 To 4
                'Cells(Row, Col).Font.Color = vbRed   //Change font colour
                Cells(Row, Col).Interior.Color = vbRed  '//Change background color
            Next
            If Cells(Row, 1).Value = Date Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            For Col = 1 To 5
                Cells(Row, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 '//Reset background color
            Next
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

For assigned Different color to cells check here: https://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-color-code-list/

Comment: Thank you Mangesh! After few modifications, the code worked for me. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Note that `Dim Row, Col As Integer` only declares the last variable as `Integer` but the first as `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable. Also row counting variables need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` could handle: `Dim Row As Long, Col As Long`